# E: Malformed entry 7 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list (Suite) E: The list of sources could not be read

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Getting this error when trying to sudo apt-get update. E: Malformed entry 7 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list (Suite)
E: The list of sources could not be read.

I tried to run sed to remove and no luck.

Please help.

Okay, after following the first 5 steps in the link: [cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-debian-ubuntu](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-debian-ubuntu) I received the following output:

```
Your Google Cloud SDK is configured and ready to use!
```

- Commands that require authentication will use cloud@postaprayer.org by default
- Commands will reference project `post-a-prayer` by default
- Compute Engine commands will use region `us-west2` by default
- Compute Engine commands will use zone `us-west2-a` by default

Run `gcloud help config` to learn how to change individual settings

This gcloud configuration is called [postaprayerdns]. You can create additional configurations if you work with multiple accounts and/or projects.
Run `gcloud topic configurations` to learn more.

Some things to try next:

- Run `gcloud --help` to see the Cloud Platform services you can interact with. And run `gcloud help COMMAND` to get help on any gcloud command.
- Run `gcloud topic --help` to learn about advanced features of the SDK like arg files and output formatting

Okay. I was able to get into the google-cloud-sdk.list file and edit it using `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list`

From there I edited the .list file and deleted line 7 (which stated clear)

I edited these instructions to solve this error: https://askubuntu.com/questions/332669/unable-to-edit-etc-apt-sources-list-file

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list
```

`

Comment: What did you do that led up to this error? https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-debian-ubuntu

Comment: sudo apt-get update as well as any other commands to install anything. I recently upgraded to 18.04

Comment: I get the following when when entering $ sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gedit:28434): Gtk-WARNING **: 02:42:15.498: cannot open display: :0

Comment: I upgraded recently to 18.04 from 17.?.

Comment: Did you follow the steps in the document link that I added to my first comment?

Comment: Sorry. I missed going to the link there. Checking steps now. . .

Comment: The zone name doesn't match what I had set in gcloud.

Comment: Hi John, I was able to delete the problem line and it solved my problem. Thank you so much for your help. Is there anything else I should do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Used Nano command to edit *.list file, deleted corrupt entry 7, and then saved.

Summary:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list
```

From there I edited the .list file and deleted line 7 (which stated clear)

I edited these instructions to solve this error: https://askubuntu.com/questions/332669/unable-to-edit-etc-apt-sources-list-file

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list
```